# I'm trying to use mouse-over event in jquery but having some trouble

Tags: jquery

I have an image of 10 people that i want to add on a web page. but i want to use a mouse event jquery so that when i move my mouse to the persons face it will show me a small text box beside his face with his name in it. Is there any possible way to do this ??

Comment: You can do it if you can figure out the box coordinates of each person and show the name of the box (person) where the mouse pointer is at that instant. Mouse events can only tell you the x,y coordinates of the mouse pointer - but you'll need to figure out the coordinates of the faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if i am right you want somethink like this you can achive [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp) with css

Comment: not exactly what i wanted but this will work perfectly. thank for your help.